# Highlight cells + adjacent 2 cells if certain text if located

Tags: vba, excel

If any cell contains the text "example", this cell + the two cells on the same row to the right of, to be highlighted.

So for instance

B5 contains "example", b5,c5,d5 need to be highlighted orange
b9 contains "example", b9,c9,d9 need to be highlighted orange.

And so forth across the whole sheet.   Multiple rows and multiple columns could contain the specific text.

Any assistance, examples appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    row_number = 4

    Do

        DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        swing_data = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number)

        If InStr(swing_data, "Test") >= 1 Then

            With Range("B" & row_number).Offset(, 2).Interior
                .Pattern = x1solid
                .PatternColorIndex = x1automatic
                .Color = 65535
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

        End If

    Loop Until swing_data = ""      

End Sub
```

This is not highlighting the 2 cells to the right, and if there is a blank cell it's stopping.   Also it's only working on one column.  Needs to work on columns B, E, N, Q, Z, AC,

Changed this line

<`<code>With Range("B" & row_number).Offset(, 2).Interior`code>

To read `<code>With Range("B" & row_number).resize(, 3).Interior`code>

And it works.
Would the be an easier way to include multiple columns in this...?

Comment: No need for VBA. Look at [Conditional Formatting](http://blogs.office.com/2012/02/27/conditional-formatting-rules-simplified/).

Comment: I've looked at Conditional Formatting, and have not been able to find a way of achieving this.   Lot's and lot's of rules needed.   The version of excel being used can't have more than 3 rules.   Hence why going the vba route.

Comment: According to your sample data, you would first select B5:D5 then create a CF rule based on a formula using this formula `=$B5="Example"`. This can be copied to other rows or the `Applies to:` can be manually adjusted.

Comment: I have gone through at least 30 different conditional formats, formulae etc, and conditional formatting is not letting me achieve the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional formatting if you want to avoid VBA.  Select the cells you want you want to apply the formatting to (say B1:D10),  Click conditional formatting -> New Rule... -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format.  Use this formula

```
=EXACT($B1,"example")
```

The $ in front of the column makes sure only that column is looked at, the row will be independent.  You then need to change the formatting to whatever you want.  In your case change the fill to orange.

Answer (score 0):

### Conditional formatting:

As multiple columns may contain your criteria you need a bit more complex formula (conditional formatting - use a formula...): `=or(iferror(rc[-1]="example",false),iferror(rc[-2]="example",false),rc="example")` - notes: I switch to R1C1 reference style before entering conditional formatting as I find it mite clear there; iferror is necessary to make formula working also in first and second columns.

### VBA:

you can use VBA find object to cycle through all instances and change formatting there (I think built-in help and maybe recording some short macros give you enough information to create it)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to use CF.   I am after VBA code to make this work.   And I have tried to make some macros to achieve this, to no success.

Comment: Please post what you have achieved so far with VBA. We're to help you when you get stuck, but not to create code from scratch.

Comment: Please as it by editing your question. I'm also not an expert in formatting, you can find useful information in help during editing.

Comment: Won;t let me post the code, says too long by soooo many characters

Comment: Try to select only the part strictly relevant for the solution / the part not working as expected or giving an error message. Sorry to say but now it seems you expect more effort from us than from yourself to solve Your problem.

Comment: You asked me to post what I have got so far with VBA.   Then when it won;t let me post the code you say I'm expecting too much.  If you don;t wish to help then don;t reply thanks.   I'll move on to another forum